Incorporating .NET 3.5 framework and developer pack in a Docker image
I am trying to install / enable .NET 3.5 framework along with its developer pack in a windows Docker image.
I researched and found that there is no installer for .NET3.5 Please see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=msbuild-developerpacks
There is no package via chocolatey package manager either
I have tried the below base images from MCR but none of them seem to resolve the issue. They either don't enable .NET3.5 or complain unusual syntax issues with other Docker commands in my Dockerfile.
Base images considered:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5 as base image

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20191008-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:3.5


Is there a way to use a base image that already comes with 3.5 enabled by default? I tried using few from https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dotnet/framework/sdk/tags as listed above but none seem to help.
I also tried enabling .NET 3.5 via DISM / powershell cmdlets but they don't help.
Even adding Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools via the VSBuildTools instalation doesn't solve the problem.
Please suggest alternatives to resolve this issue. Thank you so much in advance!!
Approaches in the Dockerfile so far that didn't work:

Various MCR images that claim to come with .NET 3.5 enabled by default
Chocolatey package manager
.NET Fx 3.5 runtime and adding Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools via vsbuildtools installation
DISM / powershell cmdlets to silently install or enable .NET v3.5


The mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/*:3.5 images are the ones you want. If those don't work, you need to describe in detail why they don't work.

Developer packs are a .NET 4.0+ feature.  For 3.5, the assemblies in c:\windows.netframework\framework serves as the reference assemblies.  Look at a detailed build trace to see this for yourself.
